# Updating dynamically added textview in a table layout

Tags: android, textview

I am having a TableLayout to which I am adding a linearlayout dynamically, which contains a textview on a button click. When each linearlayout is added. I need to update the textview of the last added linearlayout. How can I achieve that?

```
TableLayout tableLayout= (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
View subView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_view, container, false);
tableLayout.addView(subView);
txtVal = (TextView)imageView.findViewById(R.id.txt_val);
```

I need to set text for the txtVal in the last added subView when a button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last child of the tableLayout = LinearLayout.

Then get the last child of the LinearLayout = TextView.

Then set the TextView's text. Here's how:

```
ViewGroup mainLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
int childrenCount = mainLayout.getChildCount();
ViewGroup lastLayout = (ViewGroup) mainLayout.getChildAt(childrenCount-1);

childrenCount = lastLayout.getChildCount();
TextView textView = (TextView) lastLayout.getChildAt(childrenCount-1);
textView.setText("hello");
```

**NOTE**
this code selects the *last* child on your `TableLayout` and the *last* child of your `LinearLayout`.